# Array within a slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

is it possible to put a array within a slice? I tried `[][2]int`, but I can't figure out how to create an instance. The end result should be a mutable slice around an immutable 2 item array.

In python it would look like: `[(1,2),(3,4)]`.

Comment: Yep! Thanks. you can answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go syntax uses `{}` braces for slices and arrays.

```
s := [][2]int{
    [2]int{1, 2},
    [2]int{3, 4},
}
```

But you can elide the inner types in the literal when they can be inferred:

```
s := [][2]int{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
s = append(s, [2]int{5, 6})
```